# Google Play App Signing - Can't upload update

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play, keystore, android-app-signing

Alright so this is the error I get when uploading the APK to Google Developer Console;

> Upload failed
>
> You uploaded an APK that is signed with a different certificate to
>   your previous APKs. You must use the same certificate.
>
> Your existing APKs are signed with the certificate(s) with
>   fingerprint(s): [ SHA1: Numbers go here ] and the certificate(s) used
>   to sign the APK you uploaded have fingerprint(s): [ SHA1: different
>   numbers go here ]

However, I know for a fact I'm using the same `.keystore` I used last night when I initially uploaded the application. So I don't understand why It let me publish my game, but now it won't update it.
I have no idea at all how to use the Google App Signing feature, and please do not link me to the URL released by Google because I've read it and do not understand it at all.

I have the `upload_cert.der` but I do not know how to sign my game with the new certification. Please explain Step by step if possible, how to do this.

As you can tell I am totally lost and will not grasp how to complete my task if you just start throwing out command lines. For one, Where in the heck do I type these command lines? Yes I am aware in CMD, but What file location? I've been trying really hard to figure this out on my own but every link I've gone to either was unanswered or gave a answer that was way more complicated than just telling them how to do it, and resulting in still not knowing how to do it.

So please, if you can explain to me how in the world to do this app signing thing I'd greatly appreciate it. I'm using Unity3D for my App signing.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't upload the debug apk last night be mistake?  Or are now?

Comment: Also-  what do you mean "I'm using unity3d for my app signing"?  Unity3D is a game engine, it has nothing to do with signing an apk.

Comment: Are you using same keystore? Same app name? etc.

Comment: @GabeSechan When you create a Keystore, with a password it signs it with a certificate, Google considers it signed as-long as you have a passworded keystore. And I am possitive I didn't upload the debug apk. Google won't allow you to.

Comment: @maximelian1986 Yes, everything is the same.

Comment: Ok, I understand your pain. Once we have published one game with wrong package, so we have been forced to delete it and release as "game name 2". But back to the business...Have you  "incremented the android:versionCode and android:versionName attributes" ? If you using Unity to sign your apk, in Player Settings panel under Other settings menu change Version and Bundle Version Code. Also make sure that  Bundle Identifier is the same as in previous version.

Comment: @maximelian1986 Yes, I increased changed the versionCode and versionName. I have a feeling I'm going to be forced to rename and re-release my application. This time I won't Opt into Google Play App Signing and I'll just keep track of my own keystore.

Comment: I will probably try myself upload some app using Google Play App Signing feature, then may be I be able to help you as I became more familiar with that procedure. But now it seems complicated from what I read.

Comment: Oh, found that link. https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/otherbugs you can ask google team to reset your upload key. Don't know what does it means, does it allow you to send app with different signature and get new upload key, or they just send you a valid upload key. But get it a try.