# Getting "The AndroidManifest.xml of the uploaded APK could not be parsed. Was it compiled properly?" error after enabling Google App Signing

Tags: android, google-play, apk, android-manifest, android-app-signing

After enabling [Google App Signing](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423?hl=en), everytime I try to upload a signed release APK to Play Store I get an error saying **The AndroidManifest.xml of the uploaded APK could not be parsed. Was it compiled properly?**.

Here is the *Android Manifest* file got from the signed APK with the **APK Analyzer** tool

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:versionCode="227"
    android:versionName="4.9"
    package="com.myproject">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="25" />

    <uses-permission
        android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_USERS" />

    <uses-permission
        android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

    <uses-permission
        android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.myproject.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="0x2" />

    <uses-permission
        android:name="com.myproject.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <application
        android:theme="@ref/0x7f10013f"
        android:label="@ref/0x7f0f004f"
        android:icon="@ref/0x7f08005a"
        android:name="br.com.regmoraes.myproject.CustomApp"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:supportsRtl="true">

        <meta-data
            android:name="search-engine"
            android:resource="@ref/0x7f120001" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@ref/0x7f0a0006" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.mixpanel.android.MPConfig.ResourcePackageName"
            android:value="br.com.regmoraes.myproject" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="AA_MODELS"
            android:value="br.com.regmoraes.myproject.domain.entity.App,
            br.com.regmoraes.myproject.conteudo.commons.entity.Content,
            br.com.regmoraes.myproject.conteudo.commons.entity.Category,
            br.com.regmoraes.myproject.domain.entity.User,
            br.com.regmoraes.myproject.domain.entity.Parameter"/>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.mixpanel.android.MPConfig.AutoShowMixpanelUpdates"
            android:value="true" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.mixpanel.android.MPConfig.EnableDebugLogging"
            android:value="true" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
            android:value="123456" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="io.branch.sdk.TestMode"
            android:value="false" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="io.branch.sdk.BranchKey"
            android:value="123456" />

        <service
            android:name="br.com.regmoraes.myproject.push.firebase.MessagingService">

            <intent-filter>

                <action
                    android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <service
            android:name="br.com.regmoraes.myproject.push.firebase.InstanceIdService">

            <intent-filter>

                <action
                    android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <service
            android:name="br.com.regmoraes.myproject.conteudo.sync.service.SyncService"
            android:exported="false" />

        <receiver
            android:name="com.mixpanel.android.mpmetrics.GCMReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">

            <intent-filter>

                <action
                    android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

                <action
                    android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category
                    android:name="com.myproject" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.mixpanel.android.mpmetrics.InstallReferrerReceiver"
            android:exported="true">

            <intent-filter>

                <action
                    android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <receiver
            android:name="io.branch.referral.InstallListener"
            android:exported="true">

            <intent-filter>

                <action
                    android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:theme="@ref/0x7f1000a7"
            android:label="@ref/0x7f0f004f"
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges="0x5b0" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@ref/0x7f0f0000" />

        <provider
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
            android:exported="true"
            android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider976563775688475" />

        <activity
            android:theme="@ref/0x7f100199"
            android:label="@ref/0x7f0f014d"
            android:name="com.zendesk.sdk.support.SupportActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="0x10" />

        <activity
            android:theme="@ref/0x7f100199"
            android:label="@ref/0x7f0f00be"
            android:name="com.zendesk.sdk.feedback.ui.ContactZendeskActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="0x14" />

        <activity
            android:theme="@ref/0x7f10012f"
            android:label="@ref/0x7f0f004f"
            android:name="br.com.regmoraes.myproject.sessao.login.basic.presentation.LoginActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="1" />

        <activity
            android:label="@ref/0x7f0f004f"
            android:name="br.com.regmoraes.myproject.ui.activity.BaseActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="2">

            <intent-filter
                android:label="@ref/0x7f0f004f">

                <action
                    android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>

                <action
                    android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category
                    android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <category
                    android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:scheme="https"
                    android:host="host"
                    android:pathPrefix="/123" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:label="@ref/0x7f0f0162"
            android:name="br.com.regmoraes.myproject.home.presentation.HomeActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="0x22" />

        <activity
            android:theme="@ref/0x7f10012f"
            android:label="@ref/0x7f0f004f"
            android:name="br.com.regmoraes.myproject.conteudo.atualizacao.presentation.AtualizacaoConteudoActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="1" />

        <activity
            android:label="@ref/0x7f0f00fe"
            android:name="br.com.regmoraes.myproject.configuracoes.presentation.ConfiguracoesActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="1" />

        <activity
            android:theme="@ref/0x7f10012f"
            android:label="@ref/0x7f0f004f"
            android:name="br.com.regmoraes.myproject.sessao.manterconectado.presentation.ManterConectadoActivity" />

        <activity
            android:theme="@ref/0x7f1000d3"
            android:label="@ref/0x7f0f004f"
            android:name="br.com.regmoraes.myproject.splash.ui.SplashActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="1">

            <intent-filter
                android:label="My Project">

                <action
                    android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category
                    android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <category
                    android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:scheme="com.myproject"
                    android:host="open" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter
                android:label="My Project">

                <action
                    android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category
                    android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <category
                    android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:scheme="http"
                    android:host="www.regmoraes.com.br"
                    android:pathPrefix="/android" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>

                <action
                    android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category
                    android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:theme="@ref/0x7f10012f"
            android:label="@ref/0x7f0f0161"
            android:name="br.com.regmoraes.myproject.ui.activity.EsqueciSenhaActivity"
            android:parentActivityName="br.com.regmoraes.myproject.sessao.login.basic.presentation.LoginActivity">

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".sessao.login.basic.presentation.LoginActivity" />
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:theme="@ref/0x0103000f"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="0xfb0" />

        <activity
            android:theme="@ref/0x7f10012f"
            android:label="@ref/0x7f0f016a"
            android:name="br.com.regmoraes.myproject.ui.activity.WelcomeActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="1" />

        <activity
            android:name="br.com.regmoraes.myproject.home.presentation.NavigationDrawerActivity" />

        <activity
            android:label="@ref/0x7f0f016a"
            android:name="br.com.regmoraes.myproject.conteudo.commons.TabbedContentActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="0x22" />

        <activity
            android:theme="@ref/0x7f10012f"
            android:name="br.com.regmoraes.myproject.cadastro.ui.CadastroActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="1"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="0x10"
            android:parentActivityName="br.com.regmoraes.myproject.sessao.login.basic.presentation.LoginActivity">

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".sessao.login.basic.presentation.LoginActivity" />
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:theme="@ref/0x7f10012f"
            android:name="br.com.regmoraes.myproject.cadastro.ui.EditarCadastroActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="1"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="0x10"
            android:parentActivityName="br.com.regmoraes.myproject.sessao.login.basic.presentation.LoginActivity">

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".sessao.login.basic.presentation.LoginActivity" />
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:label="@ref/0x7f0f0164"
            android:name="br.com.regmoraes.myproject.conteudo.commons.ContentListActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="0x22" />

        <activity
            android:label="@ref/0x7f0f0160"
            android:name="br.com.regmoraes.myproject.conteudo.commons.DetailContentActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="0x22" />

        <activity
            android:theme="@ref/0x7f10012f"
            android:label="@ref/0x7f0f0168"
            android:name="br.com.regmoraes.myproject.conteudo.busca.presentation.SearchActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="0x24"
            android:parentActivityName="br.com.regmoraes.myproject.home.presentation.HomeActivity">

            <intent-filter>

                <action
                    android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@ref/0x7f120002" />
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:label="@ref/0x7f0f0165"
            android:name="br.com.regmoraes.myproject.conteudo.notas.presentation.NotasActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="1"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="0x22" />

        <activity
            android:theme="@ref/0x7f10012f"
            android:label="@ref/0x7f0f0169"
            android:name="br.com.regmoraes.myproject.ui.activity.UpdateWarningActivity"
            android:launchMode="1"
            android:screenOrientation="1"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="0x22" />

        <activity
            android:theme="@ref/0x7f10012f"
            android:label="@ref/0x7f0f0166"
            android:name="br.com.regmoraes.myproject.ui.activity.PrintDialogActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="0x22" />

        <activity
            android:theme="@ref/0x7f10012f"
            android:name="br.com.regmoraes.myproject.sessao.login.facebook.presentation.LoginFacebookActivity" />

        <activity
            android:theme="@ref/0x7f10012f"
            android:name="br.com.regmoraes.myproject.assinatura.presentation.AssinaturaActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="1"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="0x22" />

        <activity
            android:theme="@ref/0x7f10012f"
            android:name="br.com.regmoraes.myproject.assinatura.presentation.DetalhesAssinaturaActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="0x22"
            android:parentActivityName="br.com.regmoraes.myproject.assinatura.presentation.AssinaturaActivity" />

        <receiver
            android:name="com.zendesk.sdk.power.BatteryStateBroadcastReceiver">

            <intent-filter>

                <action
                    android:name="android.intent.action.BATTERY_LOW" />

                <action
                    android:name="android.intent.action.BATTERY_OKAY" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:label="@ref/0x7f0f00be"
            android:name="com.zendesk.sdk.requests.ViewRequestActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="0x12" />

        <activity
            android:label="@ref/0x7f0f0131"
            android:name="com.zendesk.sdk.requests.RequestActivity" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.zendesk.sdk.support.ViewArticleActivity"
            android:configChanges="0x480" />

        <receiver
            android:name="com.zendesk.sdk.deeplinking.ZendeskDeepLinkingBroadcastReceiver"
            android:exported="false">

            <intent-filter>

                <action
                    android:name="com.zendesk.sdk.deeplinking" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <provider
            android:name="com.zendesk.belvedere.BelvedereFileProvider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:authorities="com.myproject.belvedere.attachments"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@ref/0x7f120000" />
        </provider>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.VERSION"
            android:value="25.4.0" />

        <service
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService"
            android:exported="true">

            <intent-filter
                android:priority="-500">

                <action
                    android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <activity
            android:theme="@ref/0x01030010"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity"
            android:exported="false" />

        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" />

        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementInstallReferrerReceiver"
            android:permission="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">

            <intent-filter>

                <action
                    android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" />

        <service
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementJobService"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" />

        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND"
            android:exported="true">

            <intent-filter>

                <action
                    android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

                <category
                    android:name="com.myproject" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver"
            android:exported="false" />

        <service
            android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService"
            android:exported="true">

            <intent-filter
                android:priority="-500">

                <action
                    android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <provider
            android:name="com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:authorities="com.myproject.firebaseinitprovider"
            android:initOrder="100" />

        <service
            android:name="com.appsee.AppseeBackgroundUploader" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I'm building the APK using **Android Studio Beta 6** and signing with the generated **upload key**

How can I solve this?

Comment: Can you please share your Menifest with us.

Comment: Is 'derived APK ID' there in the manifest?

Comment: @PravinDivraniya No. The derived APK is added after the APK is uploaded and signed by Play Store, but I can't even upload the APK.

Comment: [Please refered this conversation it will be helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45001557/google-play-app-signing-cant-upload-update#comment77116791_45001557)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem fixed after following the bellow steps:

- Update *Android Studio 3.0* to **Beta 7**
- Update *Gradle Plugin* to **3.0.0-beta7** (required by AS Beta 7)
- Change *compileSdkVersion* to **26**
- Change *buildToolsVersion* to **26.0.2**
- Update the *Android Support Libraries* to **26.1.0.**

So probably the error was caused by a bug in **Android Studio 3.0 Beta 6**

Comment: Google pointed to your answer, for a solution to this problem.

Alas, when I built the apk using android studio 3.0.1 I still got the same error when uploading...

So this fix, is only on the beta version?

Answer (score 1):

Just a raw deduction. Take a look at your package name.
`package="com.myproject"`

It looks so common and as we know that `package name`  is used by android to uniquely identify your application and also, there is already an app with the same package name in play store(I reckon it's not yours). Why don't you give a try with a different package name?

For package naming convention, go [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html).

[How to rename packages in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804093/android-studio-rename-package) (If required).

Comment: Thanks for mentioning, but it was actually an attemptet to ommit some private information :)

Comment: It would be helpful to others in future, if you post the solution as an answer.