# Why am I getting manifest compile file error while uploading it to store?

Tags: android

"The AndroidManifest.xml of the uploaded APK could not be parsed. Was it compiled properly?" error after updating to android studio 3.0 when I signed apk and upload to play store then this error comes

I checked this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46351028/getting-the-androidmanifest-xml-of-the-uploaded-apk-could-not-be-parsed-was-it). but I can't change my package name because my app is in production

How can i solve it?

[Here is the error snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tB1T9.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting "The AndroidManifest.xml of the uploaded APK could not be parsed. Was it compiled properly?" error after enabling Google App Signing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46351028/getting-the-androidmanifest-xml-of-the-uploaded-apk-could-not-be-parsed-was-it)

Comment: check your package name .

Comment: check you android manifest file again is there any wrong syntex

Comment: I checked manifest file there is no error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem fixed after updating android studio to beta

- Update Android Studio 3.0.1 to Beta (https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/index.html)
- Update Gradle Plugin required for Beta
- Change compileSdkVersion to 26
- Change buildToolsVersion to latest version
- Update the Android Support Libraries to latest version

So probably the error is in android studio 3.0.1 stable release